# Android:How to read data from a nfc enabled health care card.

Tags: android

I have a nfc enabled health care card.And I want to read the data from that card when the card and my device came into contact.
I am using  samsung nexus s (android 2.3.6 )

Answer (score 0):

Try to download NFC Demo and go through this link.
https://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/NFC

Its help me, hope it helps you as well. Thanks.